# OR operation in cassandra cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

```
SELECT * FROM sample WHERE id = '2' OR uid = '1';
```

I got the error in cqlsh

```
Bad Request: line 1:36 missing EOF at 'OR'
```

Is It possible for `or` operator in Cassandra using *cqlsh client*?

Answer (score 4):

@Hari

OR operation is not supported by CQL. Only AND operation is supported, with some restrictions.

Anyway, CQL language looks similar to SQL but the semantics are very different. I suggest to have a look at the **[documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/webhelp/index.html)** for more details.

Comment: Then, how can I acheive OR operation (like SQL) in CQL

Comment: You should trigger 2 queries and then merge the results (collection) at client side. There is no other way around right now.

Comment: can suggest me any example for this because i am very new in cassandra

Comment: As @doanduyhai said, just run two separate queries and combine the results client-side: `SELECT * FROM sample WHERE id = '2';` and `SELECT * FROM sample WHERE uid = '1';`

Comment: thanks @doanduyhai is right but I am afraid about how  it efficient while merging with two resultant query. If I merge two resultant query, I thought it may get complex because I have lot of data in the table.

Answer (score 4):

While doanduyhai is right in principle, there is the 'IN' operator if you need to restrict on *the same column*:

```
cqlsh:demodb> SELECT * FROM sample WHERE id IN ('2','1');
```

Have a look at [the documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/webhelp/index.html#cql/cql_using/use-columns-sort_t.html).

The kind of operation that is available to you depends heavily on the data model. I highly recommend [the data model section in datastax' documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/webhelp/index.html#cql/ddl/ddl_anatomy_table_c.html#concept_ds_qqw_1dy_zj).

Comment: Careful, the WHERE clause does not apply to the same column: *WHERE id = '2' OR uid = '1';*. First condition applies to **id** column, second condition applies to **uid** column. The IN clause does not work here

Comment: I added emphasis on the proposed use case. Your query seems slightly strange and suggests that more work on the data model is necessary. If you need to query two completely different indexes, you might want to create two differently organized tables/column families for optimal read performance.

Comment: @omnibear thanks for ur answer.. But in your case you were compare values with single column name as id. And I need to compare two columns as ID & UID. And doanduyhai is right but I am afraid about how  it efficient while merging with two resultant query. If I merge two resultant query, I thought it may get complex because I have lot of data in the table

Comment: @HariHaran Could you update your question and give us the use case? That would help to understand the issue better and maybe come up with a different solution.

Comment: id | uid | expid | value ----+------+-------+------------------- 4 | babu | hari | how are you 3 | hari | babu | how are you 5 | babu | hari | this is test case 2 | hari | babu | how are you 1 | hari | babu | how are you SELECT value FROM test WHERE id = 'babu' OR expid = 'babu'; i want the result if babu in uid or expid result value. if i use two select query mean i will get the result sperately i cant merge the value chat

Comment: @HariHaran please edit your original question and add more information (comments are not good for this). Please describe your use case / what kind of information your application is supposed to store in Cassandra and what kind of queries you want to run on an abstract level.